# Undo recovery from swap file in vim

Tags: vim

Right before committing a major change, I accidentally "recovered" the file from an old and outdated swap file in vim. My changes seem to be gone. I've tried exploring the undo tree but large chunks of changes are still missing. Is there anyway I can undo the recover operation or am I doomed?

Comment: What happens when you try to open the file now?  Does it say there is still a swap file?

Comment: On my system I just get one more tilde ~ for every swap file of a swap file of .. open. Did you check that? I mean there should be a file myfile.txt~ which if opened then it causes myfile.txt~~ to be created

Comment: Yeah, the swap file is still there; there's only one swap file.

Comment: I'm facing same issue. How did you recover it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tried this myself (with persistent undo enabled; Vim version 7.3.823). The old changes were still showing (in `:undolist`, though I usually use a plugin like Gundo or Undotree to visualize it), but when attempting to restore, I get

```
E438: u_undo: line numbers wrong
```

Seems like Vim cannot handle this situation. Note that you've been warned; the recovery explictly warns:

```
Recovery completed. You should check if everything is OK.
E308: Warning: Original file may have been changed
```

Comment: I just tried to reproduce with latest Vim 7.4.140; there, I got `E310` and the old swap file wasn't applied to the updated file (which would have prevented your problem).

Comment: I used Undotree with persistent undo enabled and a partial history was available, but like you I encountered the "line numbers wrong" error; applying historical edits resulted in a somewhat garbled source file as a result.

Comment: With Undotree, you can at least grab the diffs between the changes (show in the bottom window) and later apply them by hand. Not ideal, but the best you can hope for.

Comment: Yeah -- you've been warned but too late to do anything about it

Answer (score 13):

The following works for me to recover the file, with undo history as well:

1. Assume you have my_file, that has some persistent undo history + unsaved changes in .my_file.swp
2. Open file with vim, and press r to get the recovery version
3. Save recovery version to temporary location e.g. :w /tmp/%
4. Close without saving (:q!). Open file again, and press d to delete swap file
5. Optional: compare /tmp/my_file and my_file to make sure you want the recovered version
6. Manually add changes from /tmp/my_file (e.g. ggdG and :r /tmp/% )

This can probably be simplified, but this works for me.

PS: This does not give you the undo history for the changes between the on-disk and recovered version of the file, that appears as one big edit in the history.

Comment: Much more useful than accepted answer.  As long as you haven't saved the recovered file over the original, then it definitely isn't too late!

Comment: It's not necessary to completely exit vim in step 4. I was able to force-reload with `:e!`

Answer (score 7):

After accidentally recovering the file you can simply type `:q!` to exit vim without saving the recovered changes - this will leave your original file intact and the swap file where it is.

The next time you open the file, you'll see the same prompt - press `D` to delete the swap file, or abort and find it manually (and possibly delete any other swap files in the same location)